# Bokeh: update zoom plot when hide something on legend

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have the following graph in Bokeh:

[image]

I'd like to know if there are some commands in Bokeh library that allows me to update the y axis (or box zoom my plot) when I hide some series on the legend. Example: when I hide the first pair of bars from legend, I'd like this to be the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

imports:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
import numpy as np
output_notebook()
```

the draw code:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = y1 + 1.2
y3 = 0.1 * x**2
fig = figure(plot_height=250)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y1=y1, y2=y2, y3=y3))

line1 = fig.line("x", "y1", source=source, legend="Y1", color="red", line_width=3)
line2 = fig.line("x", "y2", source=source, legend="Y2", color="green", line_width=3)
line3 = fig.line("x", "y3", source=source, legend="Y3", color="blue", line_width=3)

legend = fig.legend[0]
legend.click_policy = "hide"

def callback(fig=fig, legend=fig.legend[0]):
    y_range = fig.y_range
    y_range.have_updated_interactively = False
    y_range.renderers = [item.renderers[0] for item in legend.items if item.renderers[0].visible]
    Bokeh.index[fig.id].plot_canvas_view.update_dataranges()

for item in legend.items:
    item.renderers[0].js_on_change("visible", CustomJS.from_py_func(callback))

show(fig)
```

the result:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/ruoyu0088/8e2d5fb768ee837d3cb59943f944c61f

Comment: Thank you, do you also know if the change in the axis rescaling can be made more "fluid"?

Answer (score 2):

In modern Bokeh, `DataRange1d` class (it's used to create a range by default if you don't specify any) has the `only_visible` property.

To do what you want, just specify `y_range=DataRange1d(only_visible=True)` in the call to `figure`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, since currently (as of Bokeh `0.12.13`) the interactive legend does not expose any events or hooks to make this possible. It seems like a reasonable feature and perhaps not too hard to implement, so I'd encourage you to make an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

There might be other more roundabout ways to accomplish something like this, but it would require some exploration and iteration which SO is not really good for. I'd suggest posting to the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh) if you'd like to continue trying to find a workaround solution.

Comment: I post the issue on the public mailing list, thank you for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with Bokeh 1.3.4 like I am, [Bryan from Bokeh recommends](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bokeh-update-zoom-plot-or-axis-rescaling-when-hide-series-on-legend/2708/3):

```
callback = """
    y_range = fig.y_range
    y_range.have_updated_interactively = false
    y_range.renderers = []
    for (let it of legend.items) {
        for (let r of it.renderers) {
            if (r.visible)
                y_range.renderers.push(r)
        }
    }
    Bokeh.index[fig.id].update_dataranges()
"""

for item in legend.items:
    item.renderers[0].js_on_change("visible",
         CustomJS(args=dict(fig=fig, legend=fig.legend[0]), code=callback))
```

They use custom JS so the updates happen in the client's browser rather than in the bokeh server.

Comment: We encourage linking to external sources but we have zero control over edits or if that site exists in 10 years or 10 minutes. Consequently, we also need the most relevant content in the answers. If you can put it in and @ me I'll upvote your answer. If you don't you will see some down votes eventually for this. "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See "Provide context for links" in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) article here. ;-)

Comment: That's an old answer. Now there's a way to do it without writing anything custom - see my answer.

Comment: Thanks @EugenePakhomov. I've been stuck on Bokeh 1.3.4, and I'll update the answer to reflect that.